# Seeing if a certain character is present

Tags: string, vba, excel

I want to loop through a certain amount of cells and see if they contain any characters in the alphabet. I created the string alphabet which includes all lower case and upper case letters. 
The point in which the cells should start to have information in them is at row 4 column 1. The program should search through these cells from a sheet declared earlier as ClassList. It will only search through 40 cells.

```
For a = 4 to 44
    For b = 1 to Len(alphabet)
         If ClassList.ActiveSheet.Cells(a,2) = Mid(alphabet, b, 1) then
              NoStudents = NoStudents + 1
              Exit For
         End If
    Next b
Next a
```

I know `ClassList.ActiveSheet.Cells(a,2)` works as it has been used in other parts working fine. The problem is the If statement is never true for some reason even though I can see the first character in a cell is clearly in the alphabet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Like` to look for letters without needing to loop the alphabet:

```
For a = 4 To 44
    If ClassList.ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 2) Like "*[A-Za-z]*" Then
        NoStudents = NoStudents + 1
    End If
Next a
```

Comment: Didn't know you could do this - nice solution

Answer (score 1):

Use `InStr` instead to test if the character is in the string.
You can use this with the syntax

```
InStr( [start], string, substring, [compare] )
```

---

So your code would become

```
For a = 4 To 44
    For b = 1 To Len(alphabet)
         If InStr(1, ClassList.ActiveSheet.Cells(a, 2), Mid(alphabet, b, 1), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
              NoStudents = NoStudents + 1
              Exit For
         End If
    Next b
Next a
```